# I want to add dynamic images in card in ionic

Tags: ionic2

I am having dynamic cards in my ionic project and I want to add dynamic images for different cards.

this is my .html code:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title *ngFor="let file_uri of row"><p>{{file-uri.name}}</p></ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="cards-bg social-cards">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let uri of card">
    <p ion-button color="light" clear>{{uri.myurl}}hi</p>
    <ion-item (click)="OpenContentPage()">
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="{{uri.myurl}}">
        <p>{{uri.myurl}}</p>
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Marty McFly</h2>
      <p>November 5, 1955</p>
    </ion-item>

    <img src="{{uri.myurl}}" (click)="OpenContentPage()">

    <ion-card-content (click)="OpenContentPage()">
      <p>hello</p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

this is my .ts code:

```
card: Array<any>; //array of arrays
constructor(public nav: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  var temp1 = [{myurl: 'assets/img/advance-card-bttf.png', code: 'i am gandhar'},
];

  //console.log(this.navParams.get("temp1"));
  this.card = [];
  this.card.push(temp1);
  this.card.push(temp1);
  console.log(this.card);

}
```

It's giving me dynamic cards but, it is not displaying image and data from object.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this brackets `[]` and it will display image and data. Try like this:

```
var temp1 = {myurl: 'assets/img/advance-card-bttf.png', code: 'i am gandhar'};
```